# Android - Adding JAR File to eclipse (hotpotato API)

Tags: android, eclipse, api, jar, pipeline

I'm having this problem, and tried googling and doing tutorials in eclipse. But, it wasnt really helpful for me to use this .jar file in my project.

Source: https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/hotpotato

To be specific, I downloaded this jar file , added it to my project successfully by copying the jar file into my source folder , then added it by doing(Properties->Add Jars->And added it). Also i did a Project -> Clean.

Then once I start coding as they have shown in the examples, it gives me errors, which proves that the Adding of Jar file was not successful.

I tried in different eclipse workspaces but still no luck.

If I explain what I'm trying to do here, I'm working on a Android Download Manager Project. What I need to do is to create a pipeling connection to the request URL so that I can download the packets parallel.

Please help me find my mistake. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all Java libraries are compatible with Android. Do what RenegadeAndy wrote here, and if that doesn't work, the lib might really be incompatible with Android. 
Remember, Android is not a real Java implementation.

Comment: It seems, its not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

Remove the jar from the buildpath - and make a folder called libs underneath the root of the project, at the same level as src / bin / etc.

Then put your lib in there, build path issues may then arise if you are in Eclipse but i believe everything should auto resolve from there.

In the past I have put the jar in the libs folder and additionally added it to the build path from there.

Does it error in the IDE, or at runtime?

Comment: On IDE. Let me try that n see.

Comment: Can you actually give us a stack trace of what actually happens when it goes wrong?